# TestleAdmin Rails: How to fetch current logged in Admin or User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, trestle-admin

Here, I tried to fetch the current logged in User/Admin in the app but failed to see logged in user.

Model: Administrator

In `Event` model, trying to store who created the event by fetching loggedin-user in model `before_create` method.

> Tried current, params, user_signed_in?, admin_signed_in, admin_signed_in?, admin, current_administrator, current_admin, current_user, current_user?, super, admin, user,, user_logged_in, user_logged

Got error every time ie `NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access controller helpers, https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers.

You can try to use [current attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CurrentAttributes.html)s or the idea of it i.e. "thread-isolated attributes singleton" to get current_user in models.